# vector of distortion coefficients returned by calibrate camera function opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

What flags should i use in the cv.calibrate function to return all the distortion coefficients
(k1,k2,p1,p2[,k3[,k4,k5,k6[,s1,s2,s3,s4[,τx,τy]]]])

```
retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(
    objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None, None, None, flags=cv.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL   , criteria=None)
```

I want to find all the distorsion coef

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the answer should be here somewhere: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gga89a5ea2c97ef26165c47e792380b96bca204766e24f2e413e7a7c9f8b9e93f16c. If i had to guess, try `flags=cv.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL`

Comment: Hello Tino thx for ur answer, the problem when i try different flags from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gga89a5ea2c97ef26165c47e792380b96bca204766e24f2e413e7a7c9f8b9e93f16c , the function return different values for the distorsions coef

Comment: Example 1- : if i use CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL flag [[ 2.96536215e+01 -1.60102111e+00 -4.72481534e-05 -1.00797705e-05
   1.98390808e+01  2.95782048e+01  1.48105099e+00 -1.99042898e+01
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]

Comment: Example 2- if i use .CALIB_TILTED_MODEL flag [[ 6.95649717e-02 -4.03815891e+00 -5.25547430e-05  3.11459142e-05
   7.05662970e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  -1.13834048e-03 -2.43082358e-03]]

Comment: Maybe i find the solution, i can use a flags like : = cv.CALIB_TILTED_MODEL + cv.CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL + cv.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL

Comment: Please add clarifications and examples directly to your question using the [edit] link rather than trying to list them in comments. Comments have limited size, are temporary and cannot be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Flags you need to use

CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL

CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL

```
retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(
objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None, None, None, flags=cv.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL + cv.CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL   , criteria=None)
```

You Can know more about them [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gga89a5ea2c97ef26165c47e792380b96bcaa4ae44ce7bb854eabac902587af4dbe7)